# Why does Visualforce code executes Apex controller's action more than once on button click?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement of creating Quote using a Custom Button. I have created the button and assign a VF Page as reference. Following is my VF Page Code:

```
<apex:page extensions="QuoteController" standardController="Opportunity" action="{!createquote}">
</apex:page>
```

This page is only to call the required Action in apex under Quote Controller. Following is my Controller Class...

```
public class QuoteController {
    public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp {get;set;}

    public quoteController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        currentRecordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        opp = [Select id, Accountid, Assignee__c From Opportunity where id =: currentRecordId];
    }
    
    public PageReference createquote(){
        Quote qo = new Quote();
        qo.Opportunityid = opp.id;
        qo.Name = 'New Amended Quote';
        qo.Quote_Requester__c = 'Hassan Ali';
        insert qo;
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' +qo.id);
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }
}
```

I am using redirect so the Quote is created on button click and then shows the created Quote. BUT the issue is that it creates more than 1 quotes at same time. I don't know what the issue is but I need only one Quote to be created on button click. Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Comment: Any reason you are still using VF for this? I have a hazy memory of this VF "feature" if you used apex:pageBlockButtons at the top and bottom, but very old and hazy memory.

Comment: Is there any other way than using VF for this???